# How to turn a base ten Number with leading zeros into a string

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to turn a base ten number with leading zeroes into a string in javascript?  It seems as if javascript just doesn't have the concept of a base ten number with leading zeroes.

Example of what I want

```
function turnBaseTenNumberToString(num) {
  ...
}

console.log(turnBaseTenNumberToString(010));
// outputs
// '010'
```

I should note the following does not work
Number.prototype.toString(<radix>)

```
console.log((010).toString(10))
// outputs
// '8'
```

which I assume is the result of the number evaluating prior to calling toString.

Comment: It's not a base-ten number at very first place

Comment: @MaxZoom it looks like an octal as per the standard.

Comment: What is the actual use case? Where is the number coming from?

Comment: Leading zeros in an integer literal is a syntax error. Some implementations may tolerate it in non-strict mode and parse it as octal, but you can't rely on that, and that is explicitly forbidden in strict mode.

Comment: @JaromandaX especially knowing that all numbers are represented as binaries

Comment: @JaromandaX `0b010` is hex number (16-base) value 45072 in 10-base

Comment: @Oriol it's not in ES5.1

Comment: @zerkms See [§7.8.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3): A conforming implementation, when processing strict mode code (see [10.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1)), must not extend the syntax of *NumericLiteral* to include *OctalIntegerLiteral* as described in [B.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1).

Comment: @Oriol there is no standard requirement to run all code in the strict mode.

Comment: @Oriol as of ES2015 it looks like a perfectly valid decimal [7.1.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type)

Comment: @zerkms No, there is no requirement to run code in strict mode. I only said those legacy octal literals are forbidden in strict mode, and are unreliable (tolerated but not standard) in non-strict mode.

Comment: @Oriol actually that's what you said: "Leading zeros in an integer literal is a syntax error", which is not exactly valid, since it's not a syntax error.

Comment: @Oriol - if you put that as the answer I will accept it.  I had no idea it was considered a syntax error and resolves my confusion.  To everyone else - the use-case is defensive coding.  I wanted my function to treat all numbers as base ten and to disregard leading zeroes.  I appreciate all the feedback - got some good laughs.

Comment: @zerkms You linked the ToNumber applied to string type. But that's not how literals are parsed. You should look http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals instead.

Comment: @Oriol oh right, I simply ctrl+f and didn't check the section name, such a shame, thanks :-)

Comment: @zerkms - I just tried in node using strict mode and Oriol is correct "SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode".  I will dig in later when I have some time to find out if this is implementation specific.

Comment: @aaaaaa that's right - it's not allowed in a strict mode. In non-strict ES5.1 it's still a perfectly valid literal.

Comment: This was very fun and instructive to read as I tried to answer the question. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that decimal integer literals can't have leading zeros:

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0
    NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits(opt)
```

However, ECMAScript 3 allowed (as an optional extension) to parse literals with leading zeros in base 8:

```
OctalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 OctalDigit
    OctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit
```

But [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) forbade doing that in strict-mode:

> A conforming implementation, when processing [strict mode code (see
>   10.1.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1), must not extend the syntax of *NumericLiteral* to include *OctalIntegerLiteral* as described in [B.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1).

[ECMAScript 6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals) introduces *BinaryIntegerLiteral* and *OctalIntegerLiteral*, so now we have more coherent literals:

- *BinaryIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0b` or `0B`.
- *OctalIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0o` or `0O`.
- *HexIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0x` or `0X`.

The old *OctalIntegerLiteral* extension has been renamed to *LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral*, which is still allowed in non-strict mode.

Therefore, `010` is a syntax error, which may be tolerated by some browsers only in non-strict mode. But you can't rely on that, and even then it will produce the number `8`.

Comment: It also makes sense to mention that the "transformation" happens on the moment of the call and that as a function author OP should not worry about how the argument looked like on the call side (since that's what was their concerns were).

Answer (score 1):

As per OP

> turn a base ten number with leading zeroes into a string

Well, JavaScript treats a leading zero as an indicator that the value is in base 8. Thus when defining number as `010` the number value in decimal system is 8 `(1 * 8^1 + 0 * 8^0)`.

If you want to avoid that, you should pass a number in string representation and remove a leading zero if needed.

```js
function turnBaseTenStringToNumber(num) {
  return parseInt(num.replace(/^0+/, ''));
}

console.log(turnBaseTenStringToNumber(`010`));
// outputs 10
```

See number with radix [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix) for more details.

Comment: This is an interesting solution and indeed resolves my example.  It does avoid the overall problem though of turning base ten numbers with leading zeroes as '09' resolves to '11'.  The only other thing is that stack overflow seems to be against using w3schools as a source for documentation.  mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString should instead be used.  Good point actually referencing it for visitors though.